# List brand only once from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of products. Each product has a field for 'brand'

I need to list all the brands on my page, but more than 1 product can have the same brand.
How do i list the brand only once? Soi say that 5 products have the same brand name im not getting that brand name 5 times.

```
$data=mysqli_query($link, "Select brand FROM products");
while($info=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
$output .= '<div class="brands">';
$output .=$info["brand"];
$output.='</div>';
```

This outputs every instance of brand

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM products`

This should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked a treat! @Martin Majer